# Does this limit exist? $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y^4}{(x^2+y^4)^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

In a recent lecture I attended the following limit was discussed:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y^4}{(x^2+y^4)^2}$$
Multiple solutions were used to try and find the limit and illustrate how one would attack similar problems.

In particular we rewrote the expression using polar coordinates, but could however not conclude anything from it. When reviewing my notes i noticed some errors in this.

How should it be done, and what conclusions can be made from the results?

Another solution used was to substitute $x=t^2$ and $y=t$ resulting in the following expression:
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{t^4t^4}{(t^4+t^4)^2} = \frac{1}{4}.$$

Is this correct? How can I interpret the results?

Comment: Noting that $x=t^2, y=t$ yields a limit of $\frac{1}{4}$ is a good first step.  What if you substitute $x=0, y=t?$

Comment: The limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put 
$$y^2=Y$$ and
$$x=r\cos(t)\; \; , Y=r\sin(t)$$

the limit becomes
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^4\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t)}{r^4}$$

which depends on the angle $t$

so, it does not exist.

Comment: Would this give me the same results if I do not substitute $y^2 = Y$?

Answer (score 2):

If you approach along the $x$-axis $y=0,$ with $x\ne 0,$ you see that the limiting value is $0.$ However, as you have noted, travelling along the parabola $x=y^2$ gives $1/4.$ Thus, the limit cannot exist.

The reason for this is that for the limit to exist, then it must exist and have the same value *however we approach the point in question.* However, here, approaching the origin along two different paths gives us different results, so the limit does not exist.

For polar coordinates, this is the same, the limit must exist and must have the same value for all $\phi.$ However, as someone has demonstrated above, while the limit exists for all $\phi,$ it varies with $\phi.$ This is not acceptable by definition of the limit. So the limit does not exist, we conclude again.

Comment: Great explanation! Would I be able to conclude that the limit exist if the polar coordinates "test" yields one result? Or do I need to cover more possible ways to approach the point? I am still figuring out the geometry of all this.

Comment: @JonLachmann If you convert to polar coordinates, and the limit exists for all $\phi$ and is *independent* of $\phi,$ then it exists. Checking by converting to polar coordinates, the phase $\phi$ should not be thought of statically, but as the radius shrinks it may be imagined to be rotating through all phases. In a sense this covers all possible approaches, so that this is sufficient to guarantee that the limit exists whenever it does.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Would it be correct to say that converting to polar coordinates always will result in a conclusive answer? (I am asking since our lecture was very unclear on this aspect).

Comment: @JonLachmann In principle, why not? Also, in principle, one can always determine whether a limit exists even in rectangular coordinates. It's only for convenience that we sometimes make these transformations.